# Filter and sort in gridview by related field (2 degrees away)

Tags: sorting, gridview, filter, yii2

My model `Order` has the following functions:

```
public function getAccount()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Account::className(), ['id' => 'account_id']);
    }

    public function getChairName()
    {
        return $this->account->chairName;
    }
```

The problem is that chairName itself is a related field (Created here in another model `Account`):

```
public function getChair0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'chair']);
    }

    public function getChairName()
    {
        return $this->chair0->name;
    }
```

In my `OrderSearch` model I am now trying to search and filter by the name of the `chair`. In `Account` the chair is stored with an `id` that is linked to the model `Category`.

I have been looking at this link but it didn't help me solve my issue:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

MY `OrderSearch` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\OrderHistory;

[...]

class OrderHistorySearch extends OrderHistory
{
    [...]
    public $chairName;
    [...]
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [...]
            [['chairName'], 'safe'],
            [...]
        ];
    }
    [...]

    public function scenarios() { [...] }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = OrderHistory::find();

        $query->joinWith(['employee', 'account', 'item']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        [...]

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['chairName'] = [
            'asc' => ['account.chair' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['account.chair' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        [...]

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) { [...] }

        $query->andFilterWhere([ [...] ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'category.name', $this->chairName]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

I reckon my mistake lies somewhere here:
`$query->joinWith(['employee', 'account', 'item']);`

The problem lies definitely in the fact that I am trying to join a table that is currently not joining.